# Unsupported class file major version 59 in Android Studio with ReactNative

Tags: java, android, react-native, android-studio, gradle

i'm trying to reBuild and compile my Android Studio project, it worked good before installing the new version of `react-native-jumio-mobilesdk` for react native. After upgrading that library to 3.9.1, i had this error and i have not been able to fix it.

```
> Task :react-native-jumio-mobilesdk:compileDebugKotlin FAILED
```

Execution failed for task ':react-native-jumio-mobilesdk:compileDebugKotlin'.

> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':react-native-jumio-mobilesdk:debugCompileClasspath'.
> Failed to transform bcprov-jdk15on-1.67.jar (org.bouncycastle:bcprov-jdk15on:1.67) to match attributes {artifactType=android-classes-jar, org.gradle.category=library, org.gradle.libraryelements=jar, org.gradle.status=release, org.gradle.usage=java-api}.
> > Execution failed for JetifyTransform: C:\Users\UsuarioDA1.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.bouncycastle\bcprov-jdk15on\1.67\8c0998045da87dbc2f1d4b6480458ed811ca7b82\bcprov-jdk15on-1.67.jar.
> > Failed to transform 'C:\Users\UsuarioDA1.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.bouncycastle\bcprov-jdk15on\1.67\8c0998045da87dbc2f1d4b6480458ed811ca7b82\bcprov-jdk15on-1.67.jar' using Jetifier. Reason: IllegalArgumentException, message: Unsupported class file major version 59. (Run with --stacktrace for more details.)
> Please file a bug at http://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=460323.

I have one entire week trying to fix it but so far I have not been able.

I appreciate your help. :D

Comment: What Java version do you have installed locally?

Comment: version 1.8.1_251-b08

Comment: It looks like the library you are using was compiled with JDK 15. You need to locate a Java 8 version of the library. Alternatively, can you compile your code with JDK 15?

Comment: How do i do that?
I am new on Android
I don't even know what JDK number i just know it is 1.8.1
Can anybody guide me pls? :(

Comment: Do i have to upgrade or downgrade or what? i don't know too much :c

Answer (score 18):

For me the issue occured when I tried to update the [firebase crashlytics gradle plugin](https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/android#crashlytics_gradle_plugin_v2-7-1) to `2.7.1`.

It was possible to fix it by setting `android.jetifier.blacklist=bcprov-jdk15on` in `gradle.properties` as mentioned [here](https://github.com/bcgit/bc-java/issues/762#issuecomment-852056041).

Answer (score 9):

Try this :

- clear project cache
- upgrade packages for ex. in flutter we use **flutter pub get**
- add :

  **android.jetifier.blacklist=bcprov-jdk15on**

to your **gradle.properties** file and rebuild the project. if not resolved please refer to similar issue on [github](https://github.com/bcgit/bc-java/issues/762) and [google](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/172784894?pli=1)